# How do I convert the coordinate data from osm into actual longitude latitude points

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

So I've imported a osm dataset into a PostGIS db using osm2pgsql, however when I call

```
ST_asText( way )
```

I get weird coordinates like

```
"POINT(16767838.9 -4051592.94)"
```

What format are these longitude latitude points? How do I convert them to I guess "normal" longitude latitude points like

```
"lat":-36.51985035227977,"lng":148.04298681640626
```

Comment: what area of the world are you working in?

Comment: http://openstreetmapdata.com/info/projections. this shows the normal projection of the osm.  you should use a transform to get the data to ll84 if that is what you desire.

Comment: Try `select ST_AsText(ST_Transform(way, 4326))`

Answer (score 3):

If you never want to use web mercator coordinates you can import using the osm2pgsql `--latlong` option. That will store the coordinates as wgs84 lat/lon.

See the osm2pgsql command line docs for further information: https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/docs/usage.md

Answer (score 2):

OSM stores coordinates in Web Mercator projection, EPSG:3857.

as @user30184 says, transform them to EPSG:4326 (that is, wgs84 lat/lon) using

```
select ST_AsText(ST_Transform(way, 4326))
```